# Push view controller is not pushing on ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 3 VC(view controller) (VC1, VC2, VC3).

At VC1, I used the code:

```
self.navViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.navViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - viewController.view.frame.size.width, 
                                               viewController.view.frame.origin.y, 
                                               viewController.view.frame.size.width, 
                                               viewController.view.frame.size.height);
[self.navigationController addChildViewController:self.navViewController];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.navViewController.view];
[self.navViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.navigationController];
```

The VC2 is showing, and then at VC2 I used the code to push navigation controller to VC3

```
VC3 *vc3 = [[VC3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC3" bundle:nil];
[vc3.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
```

Currently, when I'm adding snippet code `[vc3.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];`. I saw navigation of changed and content view does not change and show. It just shows a content view of VC2.

In my project, I'm using auto layout. I tried remove auto layout on my project it works well. When I added auto layout it works wrong.

It just occurs on iOS 7, iOS 8 work well.

Please, help me to resolve the bug. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are displaying your VC2 on top of the pushed view controller. What is the reason to have one view controller as a child of a navigation controller? Instead, have a common ancestor of both VC2 and the navigation controller, or put your VC2 somewhere else in the view hierarchy, not on top of of the navigation controller's `view`, which holds the entire navigation controller (including contained controllers in the push stack) view hierarchy.

Comment: Your answer is right. However, I have a small question. Why do it only occur on iOS 7?

Comment: Most likely the internal view hierarchy changed, or Apple places the pushed view above other views.